# Need help completing unit test for angular $modal

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to get the "make sure modalInstance.result.then is executed" test in my code to pass. Right now it says `Expected [ undefined, 'http://www.link1.com', 'http://www.link2.com', 'http://www.link3.com' ] to contain 'http://www.pressboardmedia.com'` I believe this has something to do with the promise needing to be mocked so it passes along the campaignLink but I am unsure if this is the problem and cannot seem to get it to work regardless. please let know if you have any ideas.

Thanks!

Controller File

```
angular.module('pb.campaignLinks.controllers')
    .controller('CampaignLinksController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$modal', '$stateParams', 'global', 'campaignLinkService', function ($scope, $timeout, $modal, $stateParams, global, campaignLinkService) {

        $scope.init = function (currentView) {
            $scope.partialViews = {
                campaignLinkList: "/app/campaignLinks/views/_list.html",
            };
            $scope.currentView = currentView;
            $scope.getCampaignLinks(currentView, 10);
        };

        $scope.getCampaignLinks = function (currentView, length, continuationToken) {
            // When loading list items, display loading image
            if ($scope.campaignLinks) $scope.campaignLinks.loading = true;
            var promiseObj = null;
            if (currentView.campaignId && currentView.campaignId !== 0 && !currentView.buyRequestId) {
                promiseObj = campaignLinkService.getCampaignLinks(global.activeOrganizationId, currentView.campaignId, length, continuationToken)
            } else if (currentView.campaignId && currentView.buyRequestId && currentView.campaignId !== 0 && currentView.buyRequestId !== '') {
                promiseObj = campaignLinkService.getCampaignBuyRequestLinks(global.activeOrganizationId, currentView.campaignId, currentView.buyRequestId, length, continuationToken);
            } else if (currentView.webSiteId && currentView.buyRequestId && currentView.webSiteId !== 0 && currentView.buyRequestId !== '') {
                promiseObj = campaignLinkService.getWebSiteBuyRequestLinks(global.activeOrganizationId, currentView.webSiteId, currentView.buyRequestId, length, continuationToken);
            } 

            if (promiseObj) {
                promiseObj.then(function (data) {
                    // If there are already some campaign links being displayed, add newly loaded list to the end
                    if ($scope.campaignLinks) {
                        $scope.campaignLinks.continuationToken = data.continuationToken;
                        $scope.campaignLinks.total += data.total;
                        $.each(data.items, function (index) {
                            $scope.campaignLinks.items.push(data.items[index]);
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Otherwise add loaded list to scope
                        $scope.campaignLinks = data;
                    }
                    // When done loading, hide loading image
                    $scope.campaignLinks.loading = false;
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.openAddCampaignLink = function (campaignId) {

            var modalOptions = {
                templateUrl: '/app/campaignLinks/views/_add.html',
                controller: 'AddCampaignLinksModalController',
                resolve: {
                    campaignId: function () {
                        return campaignId;
                    }
                }
            };

            var modalInstance = $modal.open(modalOptions);

            modalInstance.result.then(function (campaignLink) {
                // Add new item to list, otherwise wait for it to be loaded manually.
                $scope.campaignLinks.items.unshift(campaignLink);
                $scope.campaignLinks.total += 1;
            }, function () {
                console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };

        $scope.openRemoveCampaignLink = function (campaignId, campaignLink, index) {

            var modalOptions = {
                templateUrl: '/app/campaignLinks/views/_delete.html',
                controller: 'RemoveCampaignLinksModalController',
                resolve: {
                    campaignId: function () {
                        return campaignId;
                    },
                    campaignLink: function () {
                        return campaignLink;
                    }
                }
            };

            var modalInstance = $modal.open(modalOptions);

            modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                // Splice the deleted item from the list without reloading all
                $scope.campaignLinks.items.splice(index, 1);
                $scope.campaignLinks.total -= 1;
            }, function () {
                console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };

        // Once everything is loaded, initialize controller
        // init();

    }]);
```

Test file:

```
describe('CampaignLinksController', function () {

    //make module avalible to tests
    beforeEach(module('pb.campaignLinks.controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));

    var $controller;
    var mockPromiseObj;
    var length = 200;
    var mockModal = {};
    var mockCampaignLinks = {
        total: 3,
        items: ['http://www.link1.com', 'http://www.link2.com', 'http://www.link3.com']
    };
    var mockCurrentView = {};
    var mockGlobal = { activeOrganizationId: 54 };
    var continuationToken = {
        nextRowKey: 'fdsf2',
        nextPartitionKey: '5432gee'
    };

    var campaignDetails = {
        campaignId: 453,
        campaignLink: 'http://www.pressboardmedia.com',
        index: 1
    };

    var mockCampaignLinkService = {
        //move campaignDetails here
        campaignLinks: {
            total: 3,
            //length here
            items: ['http://www.link1.com', 'http://www.link2.com', 'http://www.link3.com']
        },
        //all but delete must return a promiseObj
        getCampaignLinks: jasmine.createSpy('mockCampaignLinkService.getCampaignLinks').and.returnValue(mockPromiseObj),
        getCampaignBuyRequestLinks: jasmine.createSpy('mockCampaignLinkService.getCampaignBuyRequestLinks').and.returnValue(mockPromiseObj),
        getWebSiteBuyRequestLinks: jasmine.createSpy('mockCampaignLinkService.getWebSiteBuyRequestLinks').and.returnValue(mockPromiseObj),
        deleteCampaignLink: jasmine.createSpy('mockCampaignLinkService.deleteCampaignLinks')
    };


    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {

        controller = $controller('CampaignLinksController',
            {
                $scope: scope,
                $modal: mockModal,
                //$stateParams: mockStateParams,
                global: mockGlobal,
                campaignLinks: mockCampaignLinks,
                campaignLinkService: mockCampaignLinkService,
                currentVeiw: mockCurrentView,
                //promiseObj: mockPromiseObj 
            });
    }));


    describe('openAddCampaignLink()', function () {
        var actualOptions;
        var modalOptions = {
            templateUrl: '/app/campaignLinks/views/_add.html',
            controller: 'AddCampaignLinksModalController',
            resolve: {
                campaignId: jasmine.any(Function)
            }
        };

        beforeEach(inject(function ($q) {
            mockModal.open = function (options) {
                actualOptions = options;
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve();
                return { result: defer.promise };
            }
        }));


        it("make sure modalInstance.result.then is executed", function () {
        scope.campaignLinks = mockCampaignLinkService.campaignLinks;
        scope.openAddCampaignLink(campaignDetails.campaignId, campaignDetails.campaignLink, campaignDetails.index);
        scope.$digest();

        expect(scope.campaignLinks.total).toEqual(4);
        expect(scope.campaignLinks.items).toContain(campaignDetails.campaignLink);
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the argument "campaignLink" that is supplied to your modalInstance.result.then function will always be undefined when you test this.  The code that calls the modal close should be tested that it is supplying the campaignLink correctly.  You only want to test that the proper code gets executed when the modal is closed. We do that by supplying a function that can be tested on it's own to the modalInstance.result.then call instead of doing an inline function so it can be tested easier.

Here's an example:

Here's the code that opens the modal:

```
$scope.editGradeClick = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: templateSrv.templateUrl('/Templates/App/Courses/CourseLessonGradeModal.html'),
            controller: courseLessonGradeModalBootstrap,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            resolve: {
                data: $scope.editGradeModalResolve
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(
            null,
            $scope.editGradeModalDismissCallback
        );
    };
```

Notice how we supply a function $scope.editGradeModalDismissCallback instead of writting an inline function there for a modal dismiss.  This allows us to test that logic in it's own test.

Now here is the test.  We only care that the above function was called since we will be testing the specific function in it's own test. That happens at the last line in the test.

```
var $controllerConstructor, $scope, $q;

beforeEach(function () {
        module('appModule');
        inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$q_) {
            $controllerConstructor = $controller;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $q = _$q_;
        });
    });

it('should execute $scope.editGradeModalDismissCallback when modal is dismissed', inject(function (templateSrv) {
        var $modal = {};
        $modal.open = function () {
            var queryPromise = $q.defer();
            queryPromise.reject();

            return { result: queryPromise.promise };
        };

        $controllerConstructor('CourseLessonGradeListCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $modal: $modal, templateSrv: templateSrv});

        spyOn($modal, "open").andCallThrough();
        spyOn($scope, "editGradeModalDismissCallback");
        $scope.editGradeClick();
        $scope.$root.$digest();

        expect($scope.editGradeModalDismissCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

I hope this helps you. In this example we are rejecting the promise because we are testing the modal dismiss not close, fyi...